# ms-access to oracle convert

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I have another query out of 98 different ones(which two I cannot get to work) that were created in access, and NEED to be converted to Oracle...  Please help.

```
  UPDATE STOCK_LEVELS
  SET
    (
      STK_LEVEL,TOTAL_PALLETS_RQD
    )
    =
    (
      SELECT (STOCKING_LEVEL, TRUNC((STOCK_LEVELS.STK_LEVEL / CASES_PER_PALLET) + 0.9))
      FROM (STOCK_LEVELS
      INNER JOIN EXTRACT_WORK_001_GROWTH
      ON STOCK_LEVELS.LOC_ID             = EXTRACT_WORK_001_GROWTH.LOC_ID
      AND STOCK_LEVELS.INVEN_ID          = EXTRACT_WORK_001_GROWTH.INVEN_ID
      AND STOCK_LEVELS.FSCL_YR_NUM       = EXTRACT_WORK_001_GROWTH.FSCL_YR_NUM
      AND STOCK_LEVELS.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = EXTRACT_WORK_001_GROWTH.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM));
```

1. STOCK_LEVELS table columns:

   - LOC_ID
   - INVEN_ID
   - FSCL_YR_NUM
   - FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM
   - STK_LEVEL
2. EXTRACT_WORK_001_GROWTH table columns:

   - LOC_ID
   - INVEN_ID
   - FSCL_YR_NUM
   - FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM
   - ADJUSTED_BAY_USPD
   - ADJUSTED_BULK_USPD
   - ADJUSTED_COMBINED_USPD
   - BAY_FULL_PALLETS
   - BULK_FULL_PALLETS
   - COMBINED_FULL_PALLETS
   - BAY_QTY
   - BULK_QTY
   - COMBINED_QTY
   - BAY_ACTIVITY
   - BULK_ACTIVITY
   - BAY_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT
   - BULK_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT
   - COMBINED_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT
   - DAY_COUNT
   - BULK_PICK_PALLETS_RQD
   - CASES_PER_PALLET
   - BAY_PICK_PALLETS_RQD
   - COMBINED_PICK_PALLETS_RQD
   - TOTAL_PALLETS_RQD
   - COMBINED_PALLET_RESERVE_RQD
   - STOCKING_LEVEL
   - SEPARATE_PALLET_RESERVE_RQD
   - BULK_PICK_FLOOR_POSITIONS
   - BAY_PICK_FLOOR_POSITIONS
   - COMBINED_PICK_FLOOR_POSITIONS
   - STACK_HEIGHT

Comment: this one can also be done using `MERGE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MERGE:

```
  MERGE INTO STOCK_LEVELS
  USING
  (
      SELECT STOCKING_LEVEL, TRUNC((STOCK_LEVELS.STK_LEVEL / CASES_PER_PALLET) + 0.9) TPR,
      STOCK_LEVELS.ROWID r
      FROM STOCK_LEVELS
      INNER JOIN EXTRACT_WORK_001_GROWTH
      ON STOCK_LEVELS.LOC_ID             = EXTRACT_WORK_001_GROWTH.LOC_ID
      AND STOCK_LEVELS.INVEN_ID          = EXTRACT_WORK_001_GROWTH.INVEN_ID
      AND STOCK_LEVELS.FSCL_YR_NUM       = EXTRACT_WORK_001_GROWTH.FSCL_YR_NUM
      AND STOCK_LEVELS.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = EXTRACT_WORK_001_GROWTH.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM  )
  ON (ROWID = r)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET STK_LEVEL = STOCKING_LEVEL, TOTAL_PALLETS_RQD = TPR;
```

Comment: it didn't like that statement

Error at Command Line : 4 Column : 86
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected


                I edited the question to show the table columns

Comment: try again. there was an extra closing bracket

Comment: Error at Command Line : 12 Column : 6
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00969: missing ON keyword
right where the on already is...

Comment: Oracle wants `ON (ROWID = r)`. Fixed

Comment: Error at Command Line : 14 Column : 35
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "TOTAL_PALLETS_RQD": invalid identifier
--when I corrected to add the table name before rowid

Comment: Looks like there is no column TOTAL_PALLETS_RQD in your table. remove it from the UPDATE SET clause

Comment: Ah... I caught the error in their ways (I hope).  thank you man for your continued help~.  My last query will be posted shortly.  you're awesome.